# Post a new description of my youtube channel with googleapis in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, axios, youtube-api

I'm trying to update my description with googleapis and axios.
To do that, i'm following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22brandingSettings%22%5D%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22brandingSettings%22%3A%7B%22channel%22%3A%7B%22description%22%3A%22hello%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%22UCOsRlnWZakckW_5xYYkPd4Q%22%7D%7D

My code is

```
axios.post("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
          'id': "UCOsRlnWZakckW_5xYYkPd4Q",
          'brandingSettings': {
            'channel': {
              'description': "This is a short description.",
            }
        }
      },
      compressed: {}
    })
```

But when i'm launching this, i have an 404 error
[image]

I already test with "put" but it's not working. Anyone have a clue about my problem ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using express then follow this:

Install cors

`npm i cors --save`

Use it in node server index.js

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, i have the same error. Maybe the error has nothing to do with it, and I was wrong about the parameters or another thing

Comment: Are you using express js?

Comment: Can you check the updated answer. Last section

Comment: it's doing nothing, i 'm going to give up, but thx for the help ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225208/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-clore-nora).